# The app's Info.plist must contain NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription & NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect, phonegap-build

**I am facing issue while building ipa file in iTunes connect.**

**How to resolve this I am building apk through PhoneGap Build.**

here are issues which I am facing

> **Missing Info.plist key -** This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's
>   Info.plist must contain an NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a
>   string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> **Missing Info.plist key -** This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's
>   Info.plist must contain an NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key
>   with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I have tried with these two working solutions. Now it's working**

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation">
         <variable name="LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the location." />
        <variable name="LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the location." />
 </plugin>
```

**OR**

```
<plugin name="cordova-custom-config" version="*"/>
<config-file overwrite="true" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist"> <string>Allow the app to know your location</string> </config-file>
<config-file overwrite="true" parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist"> <string>Allow the app to know your location</string> </config-file>
```

Comment: @PieroAlberto Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just add into your config.xml file thoses lines :

```
<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>[Custom message to show to user]</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config target="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>[Custom message to show to user]</string>
</edit-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Modify the config.xml as follows:

1. Locate the camera plugin and update with:

   `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera">
       <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Used to do something 1" />
       <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Used to do something 2" />
   </plugin>`
2. Immediately after this add the IOS plugin permissions:

   `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions">
       <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Used to do something 1" />
       <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Used to do something 2" />
   </plugin>`
3. Goto the End of you config.xml file before the `</widget>` tag and add:

   `<platform name="ios">
        <edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
             <string>Used to attach photos to account profile</string>
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
             <string>Used to take pictures for account profile</string>
        </edit-config>
   </platform>`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

go to your info.plist file.create two new keys-"privacy Location usage Description" and "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description".Give them the respective string values which will be shown up when your app requests location access.IF you don't give them values the default string will be "ALLOW "your app name" access your location while using the app".Without creating those two keys you will not get a pop which asks the user the location permission.

Hope this helps.Below is the snapshot of the xcode showing the info.plist file.

[link to the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jX5n.png)